# Pandas groupby, filter and put the output in a list

Tags: python, pandas, subtotal

Hello guys I have a problem with this function that I want to implement inside my code. Assuming that I am working on this data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100, 1],[100, 1],[200, 2],[200, 2],[200, 2]], columns=['a','b'])
```

Now I would like to count first the unique entries of column "a" and then filter select only those element in column "a" that are bigger than 3

```
group=df.groupby('a').count()
filter=group['b'].isin([3])
```

The output desired is a list that contain ONLY those element of the series "a" that satisfy the filter condition (named "filter"), so that from this new feature it is possible to filter back the initial filter so that i will keep only the rows 2,3,4 (counting from zero).

I hope my intent is clear, but of course in case I am approching the problem from the wrong point of view any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean 'an easier way'? Your code wouldn't work. Or is this supposed to be pseudo-code to illustrate, what you try to do? Maybe you would like to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: 'an easier way' means that maybe I am approaching the problem from the wrong point of view... and yes this code actually does not work so means that after the filtering I am not able to return the filtered series as list.

Comment: `a.tolist()` and `filter.isin([3])` don't work for different reasons. I can only encourage you to read the link, I posted. A toy data input/output usually is very helpful to illustrate the problem. If I were you, I would edit the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the desired output? Checkout [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I don't think you have enough test data to test "bigger than 3",however you can test "bigger than 2".

```
df[df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count').gt(2)]
```

Output:

```
     a  b
2  200  2
3  200  2
4  200  2
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Anyways first I would like to calculate how many times "200" appear and then (since it appears 3 times) filter the values.

Comment: @Frank_Mrn That is what I am doing here.  groupby('a')['a'] counts how many times each value of ['a'] appears and if that value exceeds 2, then we are using boolean indexing to only show those rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[100, 1],[100, 1],[200, 2],[200, 2],[200, 2]], columns=['a','b'])

In [3]: pd.concat([i[1] for i in df.groupby('a') if len(i[1]) >2 ])
Out[3]: 
     a  b
2  200  2
3  200  2
4  200  2
```